# Starting Quake 3 Arena Server Using Config File

Tags: quake-3

I would like to know how I can accomplish the following:

- Start dedicated Quake 3 Server using a config file (rather than manually entering settings each time)
- Setup bots in the config file
- Setup teams in the config file (e.g. CTF game)

Can someone point me to an example of how I can do this?  I've been searching and cannot find an example of how to add bots or teams to the config file.

Comment: All of these are things that are better done with a dedicated server - is there some reason why you don't want to use one?  They tend to be painless to set up and the resources required are usually minimal.

Comment: Can I run a dedicated server and connect to it from the same pc?

Comment: Yes, you can.  If you have a fairly modern PC, you should be able to run both at once with minimal issues.  [Quake3World says](http://www.quake3world.com/q3guide/servers.html): Note: Quake III also allows playing on the same computer as the dedicated console; simply start a full-GUI instance of Quake III and drop the console then type \connect localhost instead of the IP address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a method for doing this on a listen server that [GameSpy describes](http://planetquake.gamespy.com/View.php?view=Guides.Detail&id=52&game=4) by creating a .cfg file, and then exec'ing that config file from the console in the full game.  That article also has a sample .cfg that you can edit if you want different options than the ones they used.

Config files must be placed in baseq3, which is a subdirectory of the main Quake 3 install directory.  There will likely be other .cfg files in here.  You can name them however you want, you just have to remember that name when exec'ing them from the console.

The GameSpy tutorial uses console commands to add bots to the game, but I believe you could just as easily copy those console commands to a cfg file as well.  If you want to get even fancier, you can run the Quake 3 .exe with command line options to automatically load your configuration at startup.  (ie, quake3 +exec my_listen_server.cfg)

However, not all of these things may be fully supported in the "client" version of Quake 3.  You may want to consider setting up a dedicated server console, even if you're just going to be connecting to it from the same machine.  The dedicated server is designed more towards being scripted and automated, and using it might be a better choice if you're getting deep into config files and command line options.  Whether or not it makes sense to invest the additional effort depends on what your final goal with the game is.

Comment: So...what is the equivalent of console command '/addbot' in the config file format?

Comment: @AJ. It's been a while since I set up a q3a server, but I seem to remember that all the config files are is a string of console commands - just drop the leading "/" and it should work in the config file the same way as it does in the console.